# where should I set ErrorLogFormat in apache?

Tags: apache, logging

where should I set ErrorLogFormat in apache?

I set ErrorLogFormat in the httpd.conf, But when I start the server, It says "Invalid command 'ErrorLogFormat', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

So, How to fix it?

Another question, I want to get the pid and tid in my module, But I can't find the api of get tid

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of Apache you have installed? ErrorLogFormat is available in Apache 2.4 and you should be able to add it it the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment， the apache version is indeed 2.2. In version 2.2, I want to print the pid in error_log, in another word, I want to get pid in my c-writen module， What should I do? Do apache have some api to get the pid?